# TypeError: join() takes no keyword arguments

Tags: python, pandas, string, class, debugging

I'm trying to concatenate a list of columns based on a condition inside a class. I tried this piece of code outside the class
`df1[col_list].astype(str).apply("_".join,axis=1)`and it is working fine.
but inside the class, I'm getting the following error.
I really appreciate your help.Thanks

```
     18         if ('col1' not in self.data.columns) & (len(self.col_list)!=0):
---> 19             self.data["col1"] = self.data[self.col_list].astype(str).apply("_".join, axis=1)
     20 
     21         self.data["col1"] = self.data["col1"].astype("category").cat.codes.values

~\Anaconda3\envs\ta_lib_dev_gluon\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   4211             else:
   4212                 values = self.astype(object)._values
-> 4213                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   4214 
   4215         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

~\Anaconda3\envs\ta_lib_dev_gluon\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in f(x)
   4196 
   4197             def f(x):
-> 4198                 return func(x, *args, **kwds)
   4199 
   4200         else:

TypeError: join() takes no keyword arguments
```

Comment: remove `axis=1`, you're working on a Series

Comment: @mozway, I'm working on a data frame. col_list contains multiple column names, and I'm joining it using "_". So I need the argument axis=1

Comment: You might think you're working on a DataFrame, but you in fact aren't. You can see the error is being called from `series.py` so your object isn't what you think it is. Add some prints and make sure `self.col_list` is in fact a list, not just a string and that  `self.data[self.col_list].astype(str)` is a DataFrame (probably a Series)